# Using Hooks in Cucumber with Lambda Expression

Tags: java, cucumber, hook

I have a feature file with the following scenario

```
Given I launch the browser
```

Now I have the step def for the same as

```
Given("I launch the browser", () -> {
        vu.launchBrowser();

        });
```

Now I want to execute this scenario with before hook such that I runs before every other scenario

I tried doing this

```
Before("I launch the browser",() -> {
        });
```

but there is a compile error
Can someone help how we can implement this before hook using lambda expression and what are the changes that need to be done in stepdefs and feature file to achieve the same

Answer (score 2):

Remove "I launch the browser" from your Before hook. Hooks don't accept an expression argument.

Comment: I tried this Before(2, () -> launchBrowser()); 
But do i need to change tag in feature file also?
Like earlier it is Given I launch the browser how do i map it in step defs

Comment: If you need a hook to only run for particular scenarios, use conditional hooks with tags: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#hooks